# LinqToSql - SQL generated by CONCAT (UNION)

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Simply put, is there any way to coerce `LinqToSql` into generating chained concats without nesting the `UNION ALL` statements?

Example:

```
a.Concat(b).Concat(c)
```

results in something semantically similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM B
)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM C
```

It would be much more readable/preferable if I could convince it to do:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM C
```

I understand why it does it (and I'm not even sure these two things are exactly the same semantically) but is there any way to make this happen?  It would make a bunch of our generated queries significantly easier to read and debug.

Comment: Look at the execution plans for both, running them manually.

Comment: I have no qualms with performance, results, or execution plan.   My issue is with readability.  I would like to know how to generate the second block of SQL using LINQ from sets A, B, and C.

Comment: Why would you be interested in the generated SQL if there is no problem with performance or execution plan. After all, that is what an abstraction layer is all about. Nobody is supposed to read it unless there is a problem.

Comment: Simple: because there will always be problems, and someone will always have to read it.  In fact, it's such a common need that when you mouse over an IQueryable variable in visual studio you get the generated SQL!   (Also, well played if you're just trolling.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL generated from LINQ is not designed to be readable, so I don't think there is a way to do that.   It would be nice, I agree.  This is one reason I am intrigued by the concept of micro-ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Readme.md), so I can just write my own SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues concatenating a large autogenerated set of iqueryables, as the nesting behavior of the generated sql query simply got too deep for sql to handle. I solved it by concatenating the items in a binare-tree-like fashion like so:

```
public static IQueryable<T> BinaryConcatenation<T>(this IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>> queries)
{
    var count = queries.Count();
    var firsthalf = queries.Take(count / 2).ToArray();
    var secondhalf = queries.Skip(count / 2).ToArray();
    if (firsthalf.Length == 0 || secondhalf.Length == 0) return queries.Aggregate((src, next) => src.Concat(next));

    var first = BinaryConcatenation(firsthalf);
    var second = BinaryConcatenation(secondhalf);
    return first.Concat(second);
}
```

This way the generated SQL nesting depth becomes drastically lower (log(n)?).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Although you do not have enough reputation to comment, [avoid posting comments as answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). You can [search for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related linked questions, to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), possibly referencing this one to help provide context.